# Increment first 'n' integers of a LinkedList<int> using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a linked list of N integers, which I insert to and delete from. The other operation I need to be able to do is increment a bunch of elements of the linked list by the same value. I have tried the following and it did not work possibly because the `.Take` on the `LinkedList<int>` produces a readonly `IEnumerable<int>` which when updated has no effect on the original list. Is there any other means to achieve this. The conventional way of traversing the list and updating each node fails a test case on time constraints.

```
static double superStackOptimized(string[] operations)
    {
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var superStack = new LinkedList<int>();
        foreach (var operation in operations)
        {
            var operationParts = operation.Split(' ');
            switch (operationParts[0].ToLower())
            {
                case "push":
                    superStack.AddLast(int.Parse(operationParts[1]));
                    break;
                case "pop":
                    superStack.RemoveLast();
                    break;
                case "inc":
                    var numOfValuesToInc = int.Parse(operationParts[1]);
                    var valueToIncBy = int.Parse(operationParts[2]);
                    var count = Math.Min(numOfValuesToInc
                        , superStack.Count);
                    Parallel.ForEach(superStack.Take(count)
                        , value => value += valueToIncBy); //did not work
                    superStack.Take(count).ToList().ForEach(val =>
                    {
                        val += valueToIncBy;
                    }); //did not work
                    break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(superStack.Count > 0 ? $"{superStack.Last.Value}" : "EMPTY");
        }
        watch.Stop();
        return watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
    }
```

Comment: Linq is all about creating a new list, not modifying the existing one. A simple while loop is the droid you should be looking for.

Comment: @Christopher: Thanks for the quick turnaround, though the while loop seems the obvious way to do it, this was a Hackerrank question where the conventional while loop failed a bunch of hidden test cases on time constraint.

Comment: If a while loop fails timing constraints, LINQ isn't going to do any better. LINQ to Objects contains no magic; it has to loop over enumerables just like anything else. There is nothing you can write using LINQ that can't be done faster by writing out whatever LINQ does under the covers. There may be well be a trick you're supposed to be looking for, but LINQ probably isn't it.

Comment: There is only so much speedup you can do from a while. And those are always about the counting variable and checking being optimized. The jumps are a constant, regardless wich looping code we are talking about.

Comment: If you care about the performance, is writing to the console as you go a requirement? Console.WriteLine can/will happily ruin the performance of even the best though out / optimised code.

Comment: @RossGurbutt, yes my stop watch showed a clear difference(in the order of several thousand ms)between writing to the console and not, but unfortunately, it is a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `.ToList()` on the linked list items, you're creating a separate list and then incrementing those values, but not affecting the orginal values.

To increment the values in your linked list, you can just get a reference to the head node by using `var node = superstack.First`, and then you can increment that value and move the reference to the next node by setting it to `node.Next` in a `for` loop:

```
case "inc":
    var count = Math.Min(int.Parse(operationParts[1]), superStack.Count);
    var amountToAdd = int.Parse(operationParts[2]);
    var node = superStack.First;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        node.Value += amountToAdd;
        node = node.Next;
    }
    break;
```